# JList not showing JScrollpane or changing size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jlist

I have the following code:

```
    JList<Song> list = new JList<Song>(this.lib);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(3);
    list.setSize(1, 1);


    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane();
    listScroller.setViewportView(list);
    list.setSize(10, 10);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,10));
    add(list);
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. When I look at the JFrame, I see the list in a single box with all 9 items that I have in my list. I tried messing with the size to see if I could get that to work but it isn't. The size doesn't seem to change no matter what I set it to.

My goal is to have a vertical and horizontal scroll-bar when necessary and a JList that is of some fixed size (fixed compared to the frame size would be best if possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the `list` to the container, not the `listScroller`.

```
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane();
listScroller.setViewportView(list);
list.setSize(10, 10);
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,10));
add(list);
```

You should try using something like...

```
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane();
listScroller.setViewportView(list);
setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,10,10));    
//add(list); 
add(listScroller);
```

I think you will also find `list.setSize(10, 10);` is pointless, as the `JScrollPane` (actually the viewport, but lets keep it simple) has it's own layout manager.

You should take a look at [`Jlist#setVisibleRowCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29) if you want to affect the number of visible rows a `JList` will show before it needs to be scrolled.

The actual width and height of each row is determined by the `ListCellRenderer`, but you can use [`JList#setPrototypeCellValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28E%29) to affect how these might be calculated.

Comment: I changed it to include "add(listScroller)" and that still didnt work. Also, I set the visible row count in the chuck of code above as 3. It is displaying everything in the list at once.

Comment: Until you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) anything I suggest is academic, but it sounds like you are still adding the `list` directly to the container somewhere

Comment: ok. thank you. I thought i was supposed to be adding BOTH. thank you!

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I'll update the question to reflect what I mean ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson My bad, copy and pasted code in second example :P

Comment: Actually, Only after reviewing the edits did I note you had already explicitly mentioned it.  :P

Comment: @AndrewThompson Hay, more examples are always welcome ;)

Comment: Well in that case, I'll reinstate the part of the comment that was not nonsense. ;)  OP, see the code after **Edit 1** in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21678096/418556) for an example of using `setVisibleRowCount(..)`.