# Updating JList Components

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jprogressbar, listcellrenderer

I have a `JProgressBar` on a `JPanel` as a `JList` components.The JList components are supposed to update the JProgressBar in every two seconds.But the problem is, I don't know how to pass the value of progress into the JProgressBar.
here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class download {
    download(){}
}
class myPanelListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel downloadPanel,labelStack;
    private JProgressBar downloadProgress;
    private JLabel fileTypeIconLabel,fileNameLabel,downloadInfoLabel,freeLabel;
    public myPanelListCellRenderer(){
        setLayout(null);
        downloadPanel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10,20));
        labelStack=new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
        downloadProgress=new JProgressBar() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
                return new Dimension(400,d.height);
            }
        };
        fileTypeIconLabel=new JLabel("test", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        fileNameLabel=new JLabel("fileNameLabel", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        downloadInfoLabel=new JLabel("downloadInfoLabel", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        freeLabel=new JLabel("freeLabel", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        fileTypeIconLabel.setFont(fileTypeIconLabel.getFont().deriveFont(60f));
        labelStack.add(fileNameLabel);
        labelStack.add(downloadInfoLabel);
        labelStack.add(downloadProgress);
        labelStack.add(freeLabel);  
        labelStack.setOpaque(false);
        downloadPanel.add(fileTypeIconLabel,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        downloadPanel.add(labelStack,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,Object value,int index,boolean isSelected,boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        downloadPanel.setBackground(l.getBackground());
        fileTypeIconLabel.setText("" + (index + 1));
        return downloadPanel;
    }
}

public class JListPanel implements ActionListener{
    private JPanel btnPanel;
    private JButton jbtAdd,jbtDelete;
    private JFrame jf;
    private download dl;
    DefaultListModel<download> myListModel;
    JList<download>myList;
    public JListPanel(){
        myListModel=new DefaultListModel<download>();
        myList=new JList<download>(myListModel);
        myList.setCellRenderer(new myPanelListCellRenderer());
        myList.setVisibleRowCount(8);
        btnPanel=new JPanel();
        jbtAdd=new JButton("addJpanel");
        jbtDelete=new JButton("delJpanel");
        btnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,1,1));
        btnPanel.add(jbtAdd);
        btnPanel.add(jbtDelete);
        jf=new JFrame("hello");
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            dl=new download();
            myListModel.add(0, dl);
        }
        jf.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        jf.add(btnPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jf.add(new JScrollPane(myList),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jbtAdd.addActionListener(this);
        jbtDelete.addActionListener(this);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new JListPanel();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getSource()==jbtAdd){
            addMyPanel();
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==jbtDelete){
            delMyPanel();
        }
    }
    public void addMyPanel(){
        myListModel.add(0,new download());
    }
    public void delMyPanel(){
        int index = myList.getSelectedIndex();
        if (index < 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    myList,
                    "Select a download to delete!",
                    "Select Download",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            myListModel.removeElementAt(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the progress value to the `JProgressBar` directly, let the bar *listen* for changes from whatever process updates the list's data model. [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513), is especially convenient for this, as the worker's `setProgress()` notifies listeners automatically.

Comment: The problem is that the `JProgressBar` is in the `ListCellRenderer`

Comment: Your `ListModel` should include a `List<DownloadWorker>`, where `DownloadWorker` extends `SwingWorker`.

Comment: You may mistake my question,the key point is to change the value of `JProgressBar` in runtime.Concurrency is not my key point right now.The JProgressBar is in the Renderer,But I don't know how to change the value of JProgressBar in a `JList Renderer`

Comment: The `JProgressBar` should be listening for changes; a `PropertyChangeListener` is convenient for this; `SwingWorker` happens to fire a suitable `PropertyChangeEvent`; you can manage your own events, but  you'll have to solve the concurrency problem sooner or later; I vote for sooner.